# how can i make google oAuth auto login

Tags: oauth

I have visited many sites where i log in using my google account using oAuth but i have never come into a site and have it automatically log me in into my google account.

Some sites will auto log in to their systems account but never googles oAuth login.

is this possible?

also would this be possible with the twitter or facebook authentications?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when a user first visits my site i hope to check if they have signed on using their Google account before and if they have then automatically log them into my site.

Comment: you need OpenID implementation rather than OAuth,OpenID handles all the authentication related operations.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading that it can be done using Cookies.

Just set a cookie with some parameters (eg the google ID and emailadres) and when a visitor returns you can read and use those values to log them in, not even redirecting them to Google.

However I'm not recommending this because of a potential security hazzard!